# Sample code for dialog like Qt Creator Options tab

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, dialog

I would like to build up dialog same as Qt Creator "Options" tab that left side page titles with scroll bar and detailed page on the right side.

It would be really helpful if there were code samples or sample applications for reference.

Comment: This is an unhelpful question. At best it doesn't have a specific problem it's trying to solve, and at worst it's fishing for someone to write your dialog backbone for you. I suggest that you begin writing your own code and ask questions as you run into problems.

Comment: Qt source code has examples like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Qt Creator Source Code

Qt Creator has it source code both in Gitorious and in GitHub.  But because Qt Creator is such a large and complex project, it can be overwhelming finding its sub parts.

The Github version is very searchable.  It ends up that the source related to the nice options page in Qt Creator uses the `IOptionsPage` as the base class for any of the pages that show up in the Options dialog.

https://github.com/qtproject/qt-creator/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=ioptionspage&type=Code

The `ioptionspage.cpp` has all the comments explaining the purpose of the different slots.

https://github.com/qtproject/qt-creator/blob/9926fc2ab12ccaa02b7f03b416c54cd58ef30b31/src/plugins/coreplugin/dialogs/ioptionspage.cpp

Basically for Qt Creators options page, it has an interface that is used by several different sub modules.

https://github.com/qtproject/qt-creator/blob/9926fc2ab12ccaa02b7f03b416c54cd58ef30b31/src/plugins/coreplugin/dialogs/ioptionspage.h

```
#ifndef IOPTIONSPAGE_H
#define IOPTIONSPAGE_H

#include <coreplugin/id.h>

#include <QIcon>
#include <QObject>
#include <QStringList>

namespace Core {

class CORE_EXPORT IOptionsPage : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    IOptionsPage(QObject *parent = 0);
    virtual ~IOptionsPage();

    Id id() const { return m_id; }
    QString displayName() const { return m_displayName; }
    Id category() const { return m_category; }
    QString displayCategory() const { return m_displayCategory; }
    QIcon categoryIcon() const { return QIcon(m_categoryIcon); }

    virtual bool matches(const QString &searchKeyWord) const;
    virtual QWidget *widget() = 0;
    virtual void apply() = 0;
    virtual void finish() = 0;

protected:
    void setId(Id id) { m_id = id; }
    void setDisplayName(const QString &displayName) { m_displayName = displayName; }
    void setCategory(Id category) { m_category = category; }
    void setDisplayCategory(const QString &displayCategory) { m_displayCategory = displayCategory; }
    void setCategoryIcon(const QString &categoryIcon) { m_categoryIcon = categoryIcon; }

    Id m_id;
    Id m_category;
    QString m_displayName;
    QString m_displayCategory;
    QString m_categoryIcon;

    mutable bool m_keywordsInitialized;
    mutable QStringList m_keywords;
};

/*
    Alternative way for providing option pages instead of adding IOptionsPage
    objects into the plugin manager pool. Should only be used if creation of the
    actual option pages is not possible or too expensive at Qt Creator startup.
    (Like the designer integration, which needs to initialize designer plugins
    before the options pages get available.)
*/

class CORE_EXPORT IOptionsPageProvider : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    IOptionsPageProvider(QObject *parent = 0) : QObject(parent) {}

    Id category() const { return m_category; }
    QString displayCategory() const { return m_displayCategory; }
    QIcon categoryIcon() const { return QIcon(m_categoryIcon); }

    virtual QList<IOptionsPage *> pages() const = 0;
    virtual bool matches(const QString & /* searchKeyWord*/) const = 0;

protected:
    void setCategory(Id category) { m_category = category; }
    void setDisplayCategory(const QString &displayCategory) { m_displayCategory = displayCategory; }
    void setCategoryIcon(const QString &categoryIcon) { m_categoryIcon = categoryIcon; }

    Id m_category;
    QString m_displayCategory;
    QString m_categoryIcon;
};

} // namespace Core

#endif // IOPTIONSPAGE_H
```

The search box uses an index the all the titles/labels of the children of each options page that gets added.

```
bool Core::IOptionsPage::matches(const QString &searchKeyWord) const
{
    if (!m_keywordsInitialized) {
        IOptionsPage *that = const_cast<IOptionsPage *>(this);
        QWidget *widget = that->widget();
        if (!widget)
            return false;
        // find common subwidgets
        foreach (const QLabel *label, widget->findChildren<QLabel *>())
            m_keywords << label->text();
        foreach (const QCheckBox *checkbox, widget->findChildren<QCheckBox *>())
            m_keywords << checkbox->text();
        foreach (const QPushButton *pushButton, widget->findChildren<QPushButton *>())
            m_keywords << pushButton->text();
        foreach (const QGroupBox *groupBox, widget->findChildren<QGroupBox *>())
            m_keywords << groupBox->title();

        // clean up accelerators
        QMutableStringListIterator it(m_keywords);
        while (it.hasNext())
            it.next().remove(QLatin1Char('&'));
        m_keywordsInitialized = true;
    }
    foreach (const QString &keyword, m_keywords)
        if (keyword.contains(searchKeyWord, Qt::CaseInsensitive))
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

Finding the rest of the components of the original dialog may take some time, but it is doable.

### Included Example

When in `Qt Creator > Welcome (tab) > Examples`, the best one for a complex settings dialog is probably:

Tab Dialog Example

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-dialogs-tabdialog-example.html

### Persistent Settings

`QSettings` is probably the best bet for storing settings.  Other options include `XML`, and `JSON`.  Qt 5 has a great implementation of `JSON`.

Hope that helps.